# How to make model of array object in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart-null-safety

[
{
"Id": 1,
"Value": "Planned Annual"
},
{
"Id": 2,
"Value": "Unplanned annual"
},
{
"Id": 3,
"Value": "Sick Leave"
},
{
"Id": 4,
"Value": "Working From Home"
},
{
"Id": 5,
"Value": "Excuse"
},
{
"Id": 6,
"Value": "Maternity leave"
},
{
"Id": 7,
"Value": "Compassionate Leave"
},
{
"Id": 1002,
"Value": "Additional Leave"
}
]

Comment: Sorry, what is it that you are asking exactly? Could you rephrase your question and provide more information?

Comment: the problem that i dont know how to parse this data from json in Api so I need to make model to parse it

Comment: List of this Items in api how to parse in model  ...code in api                                            [
    {
        "Id": 1,
        "Value": "Planned Annual"},   ]

Answer (score 0):

create a model as below :

```
class APIResponse {
  int id;
  String value;

  APIResponse({this.id, this.value});

  APIResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['Id'];
    value = json['Value'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['Id'] = this.id;
    data['Value'] = this.value;
    return data;
  }
}
```

Then at API response you can get response like below:

```
List<APIResposne> list =[];
var result = jsonDecode(response.body);
for(int i=0; i < result.length; i++){
  list.add(APIResponse.fromjson(result[i]));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for model very helpful but i use Dio Package

Answer (score 0):

for converting JSON into model, use dart::convert library and function JsonDecode.

Lets say, your JSON is in variable "json", then the code would look like this:

```
Map<String, dynamic> your_model_map = jsonDecode(json);
```

Hope this answered your question, if not, provide us with more description of your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Make Model from:

Following links:

1 [jsonToDartModel](https://ashamp.github.io/jsonToDartModel/)

2 [jsonToDartModel](https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/)

Generate model class

```
class APIResponse {
  int id;
  String value;

  APIResponse({this.id, this.value});

  APIResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['Id'];
    value = json['Value'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['Id'] = this.id;
    data['Value'] = this.value;
    return data;
  }
}
```

Then map it model class if you are using Dio. no need to decode.

```
final responseData = response.data;
final List<APIResponse> APIResponseList = responseData.map((item) => APIResponse.fromJson(item)).toList()
```

DropDownList with model: just use your model class list instead of string-list.

```
DropdownButton<String>( 
  underline: SizedBox(), 
   icon: Icon(Icons.more_vert), 
    items: list.map((value) {
        return DropdownMenuItem<String>( value: value,child: Text(value), );
     }).toList(), onChanged: (value) {
 }, )
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me Have a Great Day bro

Comment: brother how can i intiallize this list of object inside drop down and get value of id from text inside dropdown

Comment: please check my answer edited for dropdown query.